# Making an image button disabled inside of a grid container

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a grid container with images that have the class of button. What I am trying to do is when I select or click one button I the other buttons are disabled. I've researched on how to go about this and so far I found this code:

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('img[class=button]');
```

var element = document.querySelectorAll('akuma');

for(var i=0; i < button.length; i++){

```
if(button[i].id === element.id){
    hypeDocument.getElementById(button[i].id).style.pointerEvents = "auto";
} else {
    button[i].style.pointerEvents = "none";
}
```

}
: The code above makes all the buttons become disable. I want select one button when pressed on the other buttons are disabled. Is there a way I can use this code and modify what I want it to do. I feel i'm close but I missing something. Help! here's my HTML grid container:

```
<div class="grid-container">
        <img id="akuma" class="button" src="images\akuma\kisspng-street-fighter-iii-3rd-strike-street-fighter-iv-s-fighting-5abdb9e5139527.5518646515223833330802.png">

        <img id="balrog" class="button" src="images\balrog\balrog.png">

        <img id="bison" class="button" src="images\bison\kisspng-street-fighter-iv-m-bison-street-fighter-ii-the-bison-5b24fe75c93b28.2342175015291510938243.png"
            alt="Bison">

        <img id="blanka" class="button" src="images\blanka\kisspng-super-street-fighter-iv-street-fighter-ii-the-wor-street-fighter-5ac0d9aaa7f3e6.7706622915225880746879.png"
            alt="Blanka">

        <img id="cammy" class="button" src="images\cammy\Cammy.png" alt="Cammy">

        <img id="chun-li" class="button" src="images\chun li\kisspng-chun-li-m-bison-street-fighter-iii-3rd-strike-st-street-fighter-5ad35f53b89034.005454221523801939756.png"
            alt="Chun Li">

        <img id="dhalism" class="button" src="images\dhalism\dhalism.png" alt="Dhalism">

        <img id="fei-long" class="button" src="images\fei long\kisspng-street-fighter-iv-fei-long-ryu-street-fighter-ii-fei-long-5b2780867c7413.7567698315293154625098.png"
            alt="Fei Long">

        <img id="guile" class="button" src="images\guile\guile_new_clothes_by_groxkof-dc4jkc4.png" alt="Guile">

        <img id="honda" class="button" src="images\honda\1419.png" alt="Honda">

        <img id="ibuki" class="button" src="images\ibuki\kisspng-street-fighter-iii-3rd-strike-street-fighter-iv-s-street-fight-5b1654057521d0.7573768215281899574798.png"
            alt="Ibuki">

        <img id="ken" class="button" src="images\ken\Street_Fighter_-_Ken_Masters_as_he_appears_in_Street_Fighter_III_Third_Strike_Online_Edition.png"
            alt="Ken Masters">

        <img id="makoto" class="button" src="images\makoto\kisspng-street-fighter-iii-3rd-strike-super-street-fighte-cartoon-karate-kid-5a70ca9b754a75.9482296715173413394804.png"
            alt="Makoto">

        <img id="ryu" class="button" src="images\ryu\Ryu_render_by_kid356.png" alt="Ryu">

        <img id="sagat" class="button" src="images\sagat\Sagat.png" alt="Sagat">

        <img id="thawk" class="button" src="images\t. hawk\T._Hawk.png" alt="Thawkart">

        <img id="zangief" class="button" src="images\zangief\Zangief_Real.png" alt="Vega">

        <img id="skull" class="button" src="images\ex\Skullomania_SNK_Heroines.png" alt="Skullomania_SNK_Heroines">

        <img id="alex" class="button" src="images\alex\Alex_(Street-Fighter).png" alt="Alex">

        <img id="oro" class="button" src="images\oro\012b17bb420ec39cec359043f6663e32.png" alt="Oro">

        <img id="deejay" class="button" src="images\deejay\4577ddcabe90881ec6dbafd6c2ff7b36-db0yjor.png" alt="Deejay">

        <img id="dudley" class="button" src="images\Dudley\842a7094a72e5d9bebd483e9e4019385.png" alt="Dudley">

        <img id="yang" class="button" src="images\yang\kisspng-street-fighter-iii-3rd-strike-super-street-fighte-street-fighter-5ab9549a256114.9478212115220952581531.png"
            alt="yang">

        <img id="yun" class="button" src="images\yun\street_fighter_iii_3rd_strike_yun_by_hes6789-d8zgjp3.png" alt="Yun">

        <img type="image" id="guy" class="button" src="images\guy\2175287-guy.png" alt="Guy">
    </div>
```

Comment: here's my Html grid container

Comment: While you're absolutely free to rollback edits to your question (or answers) I'm unable to see the benefit of badly-formatted code outside of the code block. I was trying to help, though you're welcome to decline that help, but do consider that making your question harder to read is likely to reduce the number of answers.

Comment: ^ Downvoted for that reason. I'd likely take a look if the code was readable.

Comment: @Damianclay-downing it will be easier for SO users to help you if you'd include your code as a working snippet

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll('img.button');

for(var i=0; i < button.length; i++){
    button[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var otherButtons = document.querySelectorAll('img.button:not(#'+e.target.getAttribute('id')+')')
        for( var j = 0; j < otherButtons.length; j++ ){
            otherButtons[j].style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        }
});
```